# Problems with xpath on scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to create a crawler.

I want to extract only the title of the links that I will found.

This is the current part of the code that it's important to me:

```
<a class="cor-produto busca-titulo" title="Melhorar a saúde, economia de tempo e dinheiro: Veja os benefícios do uso da bicicleta" href="//g1.globo.com/busca/click?q=economia&amp;p=0&amp;r=1472008380299&amp;u=http%3A%2F%2Fg1.globo.com%2Fma%2Fmaranhao%2Fjmtv-2edicao%2Fvideos%2Fv%2Fmelhorar-a-saude-economia-de-tempo-e-dinheiro-veja-os-beneficios-do-uso-da-bicicleta%2F5256064%2F&amp;t=informacional&amp;d=false&amp;f=false&amp;ss=8bcd843f636c6982&amp;o=&amp;cat=a">Melhorar a saúde, economia de tempo e dinheiro: Veja os benefíc...</a>
```

I want to extract only the title and I need to use xpath to do this. Anyone have any suggestion?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath would be:

```
//a/@title
```

Being **sel** your Selector instance:

```
sel.xpath('//a/@title').extract()
```

Or maybe just from the **response** object:

```
response.xpath('//a/@title').extract()
```

**Output:**

```
Melhorar a saúde, economia de tempo e dinheiro: Veja os benefícios do uso da bicicleta
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll test this when I get home. I believe it will work.